# C#: How do you send OK or Cancel return messages of dialogs when not using buttons?

Tags: c#

C#: How do you send OK or Cancel return messages of dialogs when not using buttons?

How would you return the OK message in the condition of a textbox that will proceed when the user presses Enter, and will send Cancel when the user presses Ctrl+Q?

Disregard:
solution- this.dialogresult = dialogresult.ok or dialogresult.cancel.

Answer (score 138):

Set the form's `DialogResult`:

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
this.Close();
```

This would cause any opener that opened this form with `ShowDialog()` to get the given `DialogResult` as the result.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, setting `DialogResult` automatically closes the window, so the second statement is redundant.

Comment: You are mistaken.   The form is actually hidden not closed  "The Close method is not automatically called when the user clicks the Close button of a dialog box or sets the value of the DialogResult property. Instead, the form is hidden and can be shown again without creating a new instance of the dialog box. Because of this behavior, you must call the Dispose method of the form when the form is no longer needed by your application."  -- from MSDN  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @configurator -what about a user control? how would you make it set the form (holding it) dialogResult (obviously without using this.Parent.DialogResult...

Comment: @ephraim you'd need to access the form somehow, so I'm guessing with `FindForm`?

Answer (score 35):

I assume you're using Windows Forms...

A couple of ways.

For OK - set AcceptButton on the form to the OK button.
For Cancel - set Cancelbutton on the form to the cancel button.

OR, you can manually set the forms DialogResult to DialogResult.OK or DialogResult.Cancel and then close the form programatically.

Comment: I am not using OK or Cancel buttons though. What if I want to conclude an Accept return when the user presses Enter in a textbox, and Cancel return when the user presses ESC in a textbox?

Comment: In that case you would need to intercept the keypress in code using KeyUp, KeyDown, or the KeyPress handlers (I forget exactly which one) and then set the DialogResult manually and close your form.

Comment: There is a property of a form called CancelButton and it activates when esc is pressed.  VS2005 only lets me assign it to a real button.  My solution was to create a real button and simple set its x-coord to negative 500.

Answer (score 5):

Directly, in the properties of the button itself, there is the DialogResult property that can be set to OK/Cancel/Yes/No/etc... As the others have said, this can also be set programmatically.

In the properties of the form the button is on, set the AcceptButton property to your button. This will also do things like trigger the button when you hit the enter key, and highlight the button.