# ShowDialog doesn't return DialogResult

Tags: c#, winforms

I made a form2 that shows and there are buttons which return DialogResult but I have no idea why this doesn't work:

Form1:

```
private void buttonEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    if (form2.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        labelEvent.Text = hEvent.GetName; //Breakpoint here but it doesn't stops!
}
```

Form2:

```
String Name;

public String GetName
{
    get { return Name; }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: form2.ShowDialog() what is the actual value this returns?

Comment: Set the property in the designer and you can get rid of the event handler entirely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should use

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Your don't need the `this.Close();` line when a form is shown as a dialog.  Changing the `this.DialogResult` value will close the form.

Comment: @LarsTech As can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600107/c-how-do-you-send-ok-or-cancel-return-messages-of-dialogs-when-not-using-butto/600412), this is not true. The form is only hidden until Close() is called.

Answer (score 1):

Just set `button1` to the `AcceptButton` on the `Form` object. You won't need a single line of code.